# Power shell scripting for IIS Conditional Url Rewrite matchType

Tags: powershell, iis

I have been working on writing a powershell script on IIS adding Url rewrite condtions. Here is a sample code.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'iis:\sites\Sample'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" -name "." -value @{name='Redirect www.google.com' ;patternSyntax='Regular Expressions' ;enabled='True' ;}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $site -filter "$filterRoot/match" -name "url" -value "(^test/(.*)|^test($|/$))*"

$list = @{
    pspath = 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Sample'
    filter = "/system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Redirect www.google.com']/conditions"
    Value = @{
        input = '{REMOTE_ADDR}'
        matchType ='0'
        pattern ='192.100.100.01'
        ignoreCase ='True'
        negate ='True'
    },
    @{
        input = '{REMOTE_ADDR}'
        matchType ='IsFile'
        pattern ='192.100.100.01'
        ignoreCase ='True'
        negate ='True'
    }
   }
   Add-WebConfiguration @list
```

In the $list I want to set the matchType  to 'Matches the Pattern'. That is the relevant match type I wanted for the conditional setting in  IIS. What is the matchType required for setting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatchType` is an enum with three values:

```
IsDirectory = 2     
IsFile      = 1     
Pattern     = 0
```

"Pattern" is what you want (and you can see that's actuall the default). So you can use:

```
matchType = 'Pattern'

# or this should also work:
matchType = 0
```

([Source: MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.internal.iisurlrewrite.matchtype?view=aspnetcore-2.2))

To set it to "Matches the pattern", set:

```
negate = 'False'
```

Comment: When I do not provide a match type it automatically sets Type to "Does Not Match the Pattern" type. Same thing happens when matchType = "Pattern". What I want to set is "Matches the Pattern" type.

Comment: @IshanthaKamal I guess it's the "negate" option, but I'm not sure and cannot test it at the moment. Try setting it to "False"

Comment: It was the ''negate' option setting. Thank you very much.